# How to cache different formats/representations of REST resource?

Tags: php, rest, http-headers, http-caching

I use tonic.php (http://peej.github.com/tonic/) library to create my REST Resources. The data is very stable and having long cache times would be preferable. I set the cache headers (using tonic.php library):

```
$lastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . ' GMT';                    
$expires = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + $httpCacheDuration)) . ' GMT'; 
$response->addHeader('Cache-Control', 'public,max-age='.$httpCacheDuration.',must-revalidate');                    
$response->addHeader('Expires', $expires);
$response->addHeader('Last-Modified', $lastModified);
```

The issue is that when html is requested a cURL call is made to a php page and the returned html is put into the response body:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?identifier=' . $identifier);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$html = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$response->body = $html;
```

This returned page then gets the actual data by an AJAX call to the same resource but with accept header of"application/json" instead of "text/html".
The AJAX call is done with jquery and if I set

```
cache: true
```

in jquery $.ajax a call to my resource with accept: text/html will just display the data as JSON instead of the web page (Firefox) or throw an error (IE8).
Code:

```
switch ($format) {

    case 'html':

        $response->addHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
        $lastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . ' GMT';                    
        $expires = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + $httpCacheDuration)) . ' GMT';                                                      
        $response->addHeader('Cache-Control', 'public,max-age='.$httpCacheDuration.',must-revalidate');                    
        $response->addHeader('Expires', $expires);
        $response->addHeader('Last-Modified', $lastModified);  
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, url . '?identifier=' . $identifier);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $html = curl_exec($ch);         
        curl_close($ch);
        $response->body = $html;
        return $response;
        break;

    case 'json':

        $result = DataManager::get($identifier);
        if (empty($result)) {
            $response->code = Response::NOTFOUND;
            return $response;
        }

        $lastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . ' GMT';                    
        $expires = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + $httpCacheDuration)) . ' GMT';                                                      
        $response->addHeader('Cache-Control', 'public,max-age='.$httpCacheDuration.',must-revalidate');                    
        $response->addHeader('Expires', $expires);
        $response->addHeader('Last-Modified', $lastModified);
        $response->addHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $response->code = Response::OK;
        $response->body = json_encode($result);
        return $response;
        break;

    // we don't have a suitable format, so do a 406 response instead
    default:
        $response->code = Response::NOTACCEPTABLE;
        $response->addHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
        $response->body = getErrorPage(Response::NOTACCEPTABLE);
        return $response;
        break;
}
```

Adding

```
$response->addHeader('Vary', 'Accept');
```

makes it work. However the json is never cached which leads to same behavior as setting cache: false in Jquery ajax call.

How is it possible to cache the 2 different representations and have the browser display the correct one for the requested accept-header?

Comment: how about if you vary the URL?  If I understand your problem, the browser cache is not distinguishing content based on the Accept header in the request.  If you append `.json` to the URL for the JSON packet, the browser will be able to cache based on the URL.

Comment: thanks. that did work also makes yo wonder what the point of vary:Accept is if it does not work and one has to use "hacky workarounds".

Comment: Guessing ... maybe `Vary` is one of the less mature pieces of the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in comment 1:

> how about if you vary the URL? If I understand your problem, the
>   browser cache is not distinguishing content based on the Accept header
>   in the request. If you append .json to the URL for the JSON packet,
>   the browser will be able to cache based on the URL.